# Uncountability of "plot, setting and star"

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

Excerpted from [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/11/23/writers-in-the-storm):

> “It was a dark and stormy night,” begins Edward Bulwer-Lytton’s 1830 novel “Paul Clifford,” which goes on to invoke torrential rain, gusting wind, guttering lamplight, and rattling rooftops: **weather as plot, setting, star**, and supporting cast of what is, by broad consensus, the worst sentence in the history of English literature.

In my knowledge *plot, setting* and *star* are all countable nouns, so they should each add an *a* prior or a *s* after, but clearly they don't in this paragraph, so what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several prepositions and prepositional phrases after which articles are not always required. *As* is one example, when it introduces a role, or a way of regarding something. Besides the example, you have *as president*; *as payment*; *as punishment*.

Comment: Is it OK both with or without articles?

Comment: It's grammatical, but the meaning may be different (though sometimes the difference is slight).